# TFS Alert of successful build after failed build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there away to get an email of a successful build after a failed build in TFS?

I can get emails when the build fails (which I do).  And I can get emails when the build succeeds.

But what I need is to know that the build is no longer failing.  If I get an email that the build failed, I don't want to check in until it is working again.  It would be nice to get that info by email.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this will be possible using the Alerts Explorer.  But you could create a custom web service that subscribed to the Build Notifications then implement this logic yourself.

See this article for details on subscribing to TFS events with your own web service: http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/

Answer (score 1):

I currently have the TFS setup email alerts for failure and success builds.
I think success build emails are just a noise and I want to get them only if the last build was a failure.
My idea was to cancel the TFS alert email for any success build, but enable it for success after failure builds
I have successfully hooked up the code to find out if the last build failed and the current build succeeded using a TFS plugin.

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType,
        object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
    {
        statusCode = 0;
        properties = null;
        statusMessage = string.Empty;

        var objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\tfsTests\builds.txt", true);
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "-----------------------------------------------");
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + notificationType.ToString());
        objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + notificationEventArgs.ToString());

        if ((notificationType == NotificationType.Notification) && (notificationEventArgs is BuildCompletionNotificationEvent))
        {
            var buildNotificationEventArgs = notificationEventArgs as BuildCompletionNotificationEvent;
            objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.ToString());
            objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.BuildControllerUri.ToString());
            objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.LastGoodBuildUri);
            objWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.LastBuildUri);

            var locationService = requestContext.GetService<TeamFoundationLocationService>();
            var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
                new Uri(locationService.GetServerAccessMapping(requestContext).AccessPoint + "/" + requestContext.ServiceHost.Name));
            var buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

            var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.TeamProject, buildNotificationEventArgs.Build.Definition.Name);
            spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 2;
            spec.QueryOrder = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;

            var builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec);

            if (builds.Builds.Count() == 2)
            {
                if (builds.Builds[0].Status == BuildStatus.Succeeded && builds.Builds[1].Status != BuildStatus.Succeeded && builds.Builds[0].FinishTime > builds.Builds[1].FinishTime)
                    objWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", "Send Email"));
            }
        }
        objWriter.Close();
        return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
    }
```

I just don't know how to send the same TFS build email. Do you know how to do this ?